# LAST_DAY with time

Tags: mysql

Mysql function **LAST_DAY** returns date but no time.
This is a bit misleading because as translated it is used as `LAST_DAY 00:00:00`. How to achieve `LAST DAY 23:59:59`?

Example

 `select LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `concat` it with `23:59:59`?

```
select CONCAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), ' 23:59:59');
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about a same thing, dumb solution but it will work

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP (LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ,'23:59:59');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 5183999 seconds to your result.

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 5183999 SECOND;
```